# Linux mint computers blackscreen and beeping sound

Tags: linux-mint, black-screen-of-death

After starting my computer my computer goes black and starts beeping.

I have installed mint on to my computer recently. I wondering if this problem was related to mint or if it is a hardware problem.

The BIOS loads it goes straight to a black screen after a few seconds. I don't get a GRUB menu.

Hp pavilion g6 and no changes

Comment: Are you getting any boot screen or can you access bios/UEFI?

Comment: Is the beeping within seconds of powering on (part of the Power On Self Test), or after Mint starts to load?  Do you see a GRUB screen?  What kind of computer is it?  Have you made any hardware changes or experienced any hardware problems?  Did the problem start with the first time you booted after you installed Mint?